# Is there a word for the damage women go through during delivery?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for the damage women go through during delivery? I am especially thinking about the damage undergone in the private parts. Is there a specific word people use? I thought "damage" was too general and it would be confusing to use it in such a context. Is there any better, more specific word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In (for example) a medical or legal context,  "damage" to a living creature or organism can be called **injury** or, more technically, "trauma" (count or non-count). If it is desired to be specific about the cause or manner of the injury, a prefix may be added: crush injury, stab injury, burn injury. Damage to the genital area caused by passage of a child is usually called "childbirth injury (or trauma)". Types of injury can include vaginal or perineal tearing, bruising, pelvic floor muscle damage, and uterine rupture or prolapse. About 9 out of 10 women suffer perineal tearing. Note that "birth injury (or trauma)" can mean injury to a child inflicted at the time of birth.

[Injury](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/injury)

[Birth injury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth_injury)

[Types and causes of common birth injuries to mothers](https://www.teeslaw.com/article/types-and-causes-common-birth-injuries-mothers)

Comment: What about stretching? Do all women get birth injuries?

Comment: @blackbird - follow the third link I supplied above for information.